# jQuery random numbers within the limit

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fake the web traffic and I want to display the number of online users.
This number should be random changing every 10 seconds and go around 2000.

I created code but I can't get it to go randomly in order but chaoticly jumping from 5000 to 800 which looks odd.

```
<div class="num">2141</div>

setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.num'),function(){
         var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);        
         jQuery(this).text(number);  
    });
}, 10000);
```

any advice?

Comment: you're just replacing the original number with a new random value. YOu should be UPDATING the count with a smaller random value. e.g. `total_visits += floor(math.random() * 50)`

Comment: `cur_val = parseInt($('.num).innerText); new_val = cur_val + math.random() * 50; $('.num).innerText = new_val`

Comment: post your answer and I will check it as correct!

Comment: What's the purpose behind this fakery? And, incidentally, this has an almost unethical feel to it (though I'm relatively convinced that no-one believes, or should believe, the "online-now" counters).

Comment: unethical? If I would say that it is for something else you would jump on it right away. What a hypocrisy. Why do you care what I have on my site? It's marketing trick! People are more likely to sign up if there is more traffic. People believe there the money exist in cash but it's just 5% of actual money that are numbers. This is life and all is based on trust and this trust is undermined all the time because people are naive. Which is sad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just replacing the count with some new random value, so it will fluctuate up/down. You need to update the original value with a new random value, so the count just goes up, but the amount it goes up by fluctuates:

```
cur_val = parseInt($('.num').innerText); // get original value
new_val = cur_val + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50); // random-sized increase
$('.num').innerText = new_val; // display new total
```

Comment: thank you! It's so easy, I guess I could have do more research on random function...